# Stacked frames from different videos in LSTM tensorflow. Use of dynamic LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have 30 videos, each one of them consisting of different number of frames. Each video shows a person walking around an then falls. So I want to build an lstm that sees some frames back, lets say 25 and learn when a person has fallen or he is walking. My problem is that if these 25 frames consist of lets say, the first 15 frames from a video that a guy is walking an 10 frames from the last video in which the guy has fallen them the network will not learn anything. I have read lots of articles and questions but I could not understand how can i address it.

So, I have 2125 frames in TOTAL, yet each row has 36 features. They are just some points. So, in order to feed an lstm, I am reshaping them to 507, 25, 36, ths is 507 batch size 25 time step and 36 features.
I am training the model and I only achieve 46% accuracy so I suppose I need to change my lstm format.

My lstm format is the folloing:

```
def defineRnn(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    # building the rnn
    # opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.00000001)
    rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    
    rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 50,  activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
    rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    
    rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 50, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = False))
    rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    
    # rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 200, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = False))
    # rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    # rnn output layer
    # rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 50, activation = 'tanh'))
    rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'tanh'))
    rnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = tf.keras.losses.Hinge(), metrics = ['acc'])
    rnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 25, shuffle=False)
    # rnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 250, batch_size = 16)
    return rnn
```

Comment: What is the exact the question?

Comment: How can I format my data's shape in order to feed them in the lstm!!